# Matlab - calculate rate of convergence

Tags: matlab, math

Having vector `x` and I have to calculate its [rate of convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_convergence) , for this purpose it is just return a vector of values which show the iterations of the follow series  according to `x` length  -

[image]

What is the simplest way to calculate that ?

Comment: Don't we need some initial conditions?

Comment: Put everything correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To obtain a vector of the values specified in the question, just do:

```
r = abs(diff(x(2:end)) ./ diff(x(1:end - 1)) .^ p);
```